# Best way to convert unicode in csv to plain text?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, unicode

I have a large csv file that contains unicode characters which are causing errors in a Python script I am trying to run. My process for removing them so far has been quite tedious. I run my script and as soon as it hits a unicode character, I get an error:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xef' in position 197: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Then I Google u'\xef' and try to figure out what the character actually is (Does anyone know of a website with a list of these definitions?). I'm using that information to build a dictionary and I have a second Python script that converts the unicode characters to regular text:

```
unicode_dict = {"\xb0":"deg", "\xa0":" ", "\xbd":"1/2", "\xbc":"1/4", "\xb2":"^2", "\xbe":"3/4"}

for f in glob.glob(r"C:\Folder1\*.csv"):
    in_csv = f
    out_csv = f.replace(".csv", "_2.csv")

    write_f=open(out_csv, "wb")
    writer = csv.writer(write_f)

    with open(in_csv,'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            new_row = []
            for s in row:
                for k, v in unicode_dict.iteritems():
                    s = s.replace(k, v)
                new_row.append(s)
            writer.writerow(new_row)

    write_f.close()
    os.remove(in_csv)
    os.rename(out_csv, in_csv)
```

Then I have to run the code again, get another error, and look up the next unicode character on Google. There must be a better way, right?

Comment: If this is Python 2 and not Python 3, your characters are probably not Unicode but rather [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Code_page_layout) or [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin1#Codepage_layout).

Comment: @Mark: that is how OP interprets them anyway. Since we don't got to see how he decided that "\xbd=1/2" in the original text, it could be something else entirely -- i.e., Cyrillic, Greek, Hebrew, or any other possible 8-bit codepage.

Comment: @Jongware, I can only assume that the characters make sense in the context of the data or this would be a different question entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html . Carefully.

Then, you'll understand that you need to know **which encoding** your file is in. If you've been able to find out what `\xbd` means, maybe that some place mentions which encoding it is.

Then, use `io.open(in_csv, 'rb', encoding='yourencodinghere')` instead of the vanilla `open` call.

*Then*, apparently the csv module doesn't handle Unicode, sigh. Use something from SBillion's answer (e.g. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html ) to work around it.

Comment: As I read the question, the problem is not determining which encoding the source data is in, the problem is in creating a pure ASCII file based on that data.

Comment: The way I read it (see the first sentence) is that his problem is that the special characters are causing his script to fail, and he's trying to remove them by hand to work around that. There should be better ways.

Comment: Note that the documentation explains how to do Unicode via utf-8 in csv files with the standard library: [13.1. csv — CSV File Reading and Writing — Python v2.7.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at this for a way to handle Unicode via utf-8 in csv files with the standard python library:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-examples

But if you prefer, you can use this external unicode-compliant module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.9.0